# how to get the dequeue count in azure functions with powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-functions, azure-storage-queues

I have implemented an azure storage queue triggered azure function with powershell.
Now i'am looking for an solution to read the dequeue count of the queue item to implement an error handling function.
For C# I have found some solutions from MS but not for PS.

```
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"

using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue;
using System;

public static void Run(CloudQueueMessage myQueueItem, 
DateTimeOffset expirationTime, 
DateTimeOffset insertionTime, 
DateTimeOffset nextVisibleTime,
string queueTrigger,
string id,
string popReceipt,
int dequeueCount,
TraceWriter log)
{
log.Info($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem.AsString}\n" +
    $"queueTrigger={queueTrigger}\n" +
    $"expirationTime={expirationTime}\n" +
    $"insertionTime={insertionTime}\n" +
    $"nextVisibleTime={nextVisibleTime}\n" +
    $"id={id}\n" +
    $"popReceipt={popReceipt}\n" + 
    $"dequeueCount={dequeueCount}");
}
```

BR

Comment: Please post the C# solution you found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dequeue count is pushed as 'binding data'. (Each trigger has its own unique binding data specific to that trigger.)  In C#, binding data can be directly bound to parameters, which is why the above example works. In Powershell, the binding data is passed via **environment variables**.  Inspect your env variables and you should see these.   (there's a nice example of this with HTTP here: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_stranger/2017/01/29/powershell-azure-functions-lessons-learned/ )

Comment: I have checked and tested the script in the blog post you mentioned before. There is no variable for env: in my queue triggerd azure function...